# Excel VBA- Storing Values to Display Later

Tags: vba, excel

What I am looking for is to store values for a graph. We have two relevant columns of data: A has the Name, B has the Amount. What I need to do is sum the Amounts that have the same Name, pull the top ten of those sums, and display them in a chart. Is this possible, or do I have to store the top ten in some sort of table?

Thanks!

Comment: This is easy to do with pivot table / pivot chart top 10 option, if you have Excel 2013 you can create the chart without needing the data range.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put all the values in one table for the chart to source from.

If you do not want this second set of data visible or altered by basic users you can add another sheet where you only copy the desired 10 rows to and set your chart source to that sheet. In the new sheet you can mark it in it's properties in the VBA editor as "Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden" which basically makes it visible form VBA only.

Is it possible, from script yes, you would total these up yourself in a VBA Script and write them to the destination table.

Here is some example code on looping through a sheet in excel (from a training session I held)

```
Sub LoopingThroughSheetContents()

    ' This is a comment in Visual Basic, any text after a single-quote character is ignored.
    ' Explain PURPOSE and OBJECTIVE with comments DO NOT explain the obvious it's not useful later on.

    ' DIM statements define variables that are typically used inside a sub-routine or function (both called a method)
    ' Variables can be passed to different methods to break up code into re-usable chunks and to simplify or generalize operation.

    Dim Sh As Worksheet ' used to hold reference to the sheet that is being worked on.
    Set Sh = Application.ActiveSheet 'complex objects are assigned with the "Set" statement.
        ' basic data types such as Long, Date, String, Integer, Boolean are simply assigned and read with "="
        ' complex ones can have a default property that returns a value instead of the object itself.
        ' SET indicates to assign the object and not the default property value.

    Dim iR As Long ' Variable used to hold the CURRENT row during the loop
    Dim iC As Long ' Variable used to hold the CURRENT Column during the loop

    Dim Buffer As String ' used to buffer the cell values for test display.

    ' Excel provides Range objects to work with depending on the scenario.
    ' A Range is equivalent to a users selection in the Excel GUI (Graphical User Interface)
    ' a built in Range Property of all WorkSheets is the "UsedRange"
    ' UsedRange refers to the smallest rectangluar selection that incudes all data on a sheet normally starting from 1,1 (A1)

    Dim TempCellValue As String

    For iR = 2 To Sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count    ' causes the code inside the "For Next" to run once
        ' for each number from 1 to the last row on the sheet based on excels sheet data range that is considered USED.
        ' each loop iR will increment by 1. Eg. 1, 2, 3, 4 ... exit
        ' iR in the first loop is 1

        For iC = 1 To Sh.UsedRange.Columns.Count  ' another loop inside the ROW loop.
            ' used to access each column in this case.
            ' The column loop will start, Loop multiple times, and End once for each row because it is INSIDE the ROW loop!
            ' If there are 3 rows and 5 columns the block of code will execute 15 times.

             ' get the value property of the range of cells requested basically Row iR and Column iC
             ' assigning it to the temporary variable TempCellValue
            TempCellValue = Sh.Cells(iR, iC)

            Buffer = Buffer & TempCellValue & vbTab ' append the value to a buffer with a trailing TAB character.

        Next iC 'the end of the column loop.

        Buffer = Buffer & vbCrLf ' after each column is processed add an ENTER character to the buffer to End the Rows line output

        ' the end marker for the loop for each ROW ...
    Next iR ' the end of the loop, code will return to the corresponding "FOR" line.
        'with iR incremented to the next number until it is past the desired end point.

    MsgBox Buffer

End Sub
```

Comment: So even if I have the raw data visible, we still need to have a table with the calculated values somewhere, even if it is hidden?

Comment: Yeah, the Chart will expect a specific source range. This range could be derived via calculations, VBA Code or things like pivot tables. I'm most comfortable using VBA Code myself.